# MySQL UNION DISTINCT - exclude

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query like this:

```
SELECT cs_event.*, cs_file.name, cs_file.extension, cs_user.first_name, cs_user.last_name
FROM cs_event
LEFT JOIN cs_file ON cs_event.idfile = cs_file.idfile
LEFT JOIN cs_user ON cs_event.iduser = cs_user.iduser
WHERE type !=  51
AND idportal = 1
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT cs_event.*, cs_file.name, cs_file.extension, cs_user.first_name, cs_user.last_name
FROM cs_event
LEFT JOIN cs_file ON cs_event.idfile = cs_file.idfile
LEFT JOIN cs_user ON cs_event.iduser = cs_user.iduser
WHERE shared_with_users LIKE  '%i:2;%'
AND idportal = 1
ORDER BY add_date DESC
LIMIT 6
```

The problem is following:

Regular user can't see certain types of events (for now it is type 51) and he can see only things which are shared with him.

**shared_with_users** column can be null or have value - this column have value only for one type of event (type = 50) and for other events it is null.

I need to perform following:

User can access all events except event with type 51 and if the the event is type of 50, I need to check if the event is shared with him (**shared_with_users** column), and collect that also. Is it possible to make this kind of query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT cs_event.*, cs_file.name, cs_file.extension, cs_user.first_name, cs_user.last_name
FROM cs_event
LEFT JOIN cs_file ON cs_event.idfile = cs_file.idfile
LEFT JOIN cs_user ON cs_event.iduser = cs_user.iduser
WHERE type !=  51 o or (type =  50 and shared_with_users LIKE  '%i:2;%')
AND idportal = 1
ORDER BY add_date DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: I am still getting the **shared_with_users** which user is not allowed to see (the result is same as for my query).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this as a single query, with logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT e.*, f.name, f.extension, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM cs_event e LEFT JOIN
     cs_file f
     ON e.idfile = f.idfile LEFT JOIN
     cs_user u
     ON e.iduser = u.iduser
WHERE idportal = 1 AND
      (type <> 51 OR shared_with_users LIKE  '%i:2;%');
```

Some notes:

- I don't think the `LEFT JOIN`s are necessary.  The `WHERE` clause may be turning them into inner joins anyway, but it is hard to tell without qualified column names.
- I added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.
- The logic for `shared_with_users` suggests that you have stored a list of values in a string.  That is a bad choice.

Comment: I am still getting the same result :/ **shared_with_users** stores serialized array.

Comment: @Sasha . . . It looks like a string based on your question.

Comment: This is data stored in **shared_with_users**: a:2:{i:0;s:1:"3";i:1;s:1:"4";}.